# WKWebView in Swift not working. Doesn't show html string

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, wkwebview

I have a wkWebView included in Table View Cell, that is self resizing and is filled via a pageable controller. It can be enabled and disabled depending on html string that is delivered or not. The cell is designed programmatically.

I have set up everything as seen on many examples seen on the web., but it doesn't show anything, just plain white space.
I have no Idea, what I'm doing wrong. Maybe someone can give me a hint.

Here are the code parts concerning the webview:

```
  private let webView:WKWebView = { () -> WKWebView in
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    //webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return webView
}()

 func update(entity: Codable) {
    guard let news = entity as? NewsStream else {
        print("not a news stream!")
        return
    }
    if news.category == nil {
        news.category = news.widgetType
    }
    //Set global news variable
    self.news = news

    createWebView()
    }

 func createWebView(){
    webView.isHidden = true
    if let html = news?.html, let link = news?.webLink {
        if !html.isEmpty{
            webView.isHidden = false
            // let html2 = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>"
            webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
            //        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
            //                let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
            //                webView.load(myRequest)
            webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: currentYPos, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 400)
            currentYPos = currentYPos + webView.frame.height
            webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            webView.tintColor = UIColor.orange
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
        }
    }
}

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    
          self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
                    if complete != nil {
                        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                            self.webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                        y: self.webView.frame.origin.y,
                                                        width:self.webView.frame.width,
                                                        height: height as! CGFloat)
                        })
                    }
    print("Webview Did load")
    print(webView.frame)
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you add `webViiew` to your cell?

Comment: Your webview probably has wrong  (zero) size. You tell it that it should use constraints (`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`) but you are then setting frame and not setting any constraints. You should not set things like `scrollHeight` manually.

Comment: Dosen't translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false mean, that it should not use constraints?
I'm adding all sizes manually in this cell and it works. I have reasons for this. Constraints were not able to get the layout right (or I was not able to set it up right - no matter.) There is only one constraint for the cell. Nothing more.
So why you think the size is zero? I set the size with frame to different sizes to check. The covered area was visible, but nothing inside

Comment: @koen, You are right! That one was missing indeed! Dumb mistake ....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

```
if let bodyText = news.bodyText {
            myWebview.loadHTMLString(bodyText, baseURL: nil)
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer more? It seems to assume there's a `bodyText` property of NewsStream. I don't see anything in the code that suggests that. Is there's something else you're seeing?

Comment: news.html actually delivers a html body like this:
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>